# How to set predefined time in jspinner

Tags: java, swing, date, simpledateformat, jspinner

I have some pre defined time in mysql database in varchar format for example - 16:45, 00:30, 09:15, 20:50 and 10 more.

I want to display any one of these time in jspinner I am trying but getting error
this my jspinner setup where I am displaying the time this is inside constructor-

```
Date date = new Date();
SpinnerDateModel sm = new SpinnerDateModel(date, null, null, Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
arr_time.setModel(sm);
JSpinner.DateEditor ar = new JSpinner.DateEditor(arr_time, "HH:mm");
arr_time.setEditor(ar);
```

and this my modify button code where I fetching the time as string from database trying to show them in jspinner

```
try {
    if (evt.getActionCommand().equals("Modify")) {
        String flno=JOptionPane.showInputDialog(this, "Enter Flight Number");
        String sql="SELECT * FROM flights WHERE flightno='"+flno+"'";
        smt = con.createStatement(ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE,ResultSet.CONCUR_READ_ONLY);
        rs = smt.executeQuery(sql);
        while (rs.next()) {
            jTextField1.setText(rs.getString(1));
            arr_time.setValue(rs.getString(2));
            jTextField4.setText(rs.getString(4));
            jTextField5.setText(rs.getString(5));
        }
    } else if(evt.getActionCommand().equals("Update")) {
    }
```

> run: illegal value

Error is coming in netbeans 7.1

Comment: Be aware that building an SQL statement by concatenating user input to a string creates a common and serious vulnerability known as [SQL injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection).  Instead, you should call `con.prepareStatement` and call the `setString` method of the PreparedStatement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although not obvious, the error is telling you the type used to set the `JSpinner` and the `String` read in from the database are incompatible. `SpinnerDateModel` uses a `Date` as the underlying object type

Try

```
SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm");
arr_time.setValue(format.parseObject(rs.getString(2))); // e.g. input 16:45
```